# Android ExpandableListView - setOnChildLongClickListener?

Tags: android, listview

How can I make it so that long-clicks can be detected on the child elements of my [ExpandableListView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html)?

The [ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener.html) interface only has an `onChildClick()` method.

There is no `onChildLongClick()` method - and no **ExpandableListView.OnChild*Long*ClickListener** interface either.

Comment: well in that case handle the click in the adapter..

Comment: OK, but I want to handle **long** click events - as you can with many other views.

Comment: can you set a View.OnLongClickListener for the inflated view in the createView() method of the adapter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Crispert's comment above, my solution was to create an interface in my adapter class:

```
interface OnChildClickListener {
    void onChildClick(int listPosition, int expandedListPosition, boolean isLastChild, View view);
    boolean onChildLongClick(int listPosition, int expandedListPosition, boolean isLastChild, View view);
}
```

which is called in the `getChildView` method in my adapter class:

```
@Override
public View getChildView(final int listPosition, final int expandedListPosition, final boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    // Your existing code

    convertView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            onChildClickListener.onChildClick(listPosition, expandedListPosition, isLastChild, view);
        }
    });

    convertView.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View view) {
            return onChildClickListener.onChildLongClick(listPosition, expandedListPosition, isLastChild, view);
        }
    });

    return convertView;
}
```

And then, in the adapter's constructor, ensure the calling activity/fragment implements this interface. Your activity/fragment can then handle the long-clicks as desired.